# Create Object inside a Class in C++

Tags: c++, class

here is my code

```
class test {
  TButton *asd;
public :
  test(){
      asd->Text = "Test";
  }
};
```

The problem is it won't work. Because The object hasn't been constructed using new operator. However when I tried using new operator, it return an error and doesnt even compiled. Anyhelp is appreciated.

I am using C++ Builder.

Comment: `asd = new TButton();` but we'd need to see your `TButton` class and your error.

Comment: So what is the error when you use new operator?

Comment: E2285 Could not find a match for 'TButton::TButton(). TButton class is a built-in class, it is not something that I made.

Comment: You have to know how to create a `TButton`. What ctors does it have? Looks like it doesn't have a default constructor, i.e. `TButton::TButton()`.

Comment: @JameyD Tried that, the error is as I specified on comment above.

Comment: @songyuanyao well, it is easy to create TButton outside a class. This code works perfectly : TButton *asd; asd = new TButton(this); but inside the class, this code won't work.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Form2

Comment: here is the code that totally working fine. I wonder why the same code won't work when I Put it inside my class function. http://i.snag.gy/ViYSD.jpg

Comment: this is a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
  test() : asd(new TButton(...)) {
      asd->Text = "Test";
  }
```

Otherwise you're using an uninitialized pointer.  Note the syntax I've used there is called an "initialization list" and many times it's the best way to write a constructor.

Of course you'll need to add a matching destructor:

```
  ~test() {
    delete asd;
  }
```

But then the "rule of three" (or five) will tell you to add even more methods, so instead, simply avoid using a raw pointer, and use a "smart pointer":

```
class test {
  std::unique_ptr<TButton> asd;
public :
  test() : asd(new TButton(...)) {
      asd->Text = "Test";
  }
};
```

Now you don't need a user-defined destructor.

Comment: How would you know there's a constructor for `TButton` that takes no parameters?

Comment: @JameyD: I don't know that, but thanks for pointing it out, even if obliquely.

Comment: 1st code, isn't working. it throws the same error as before.  
[E2285 Could not find a match for 'TButton::TButton()]

Comment: as for the 3rd code, it wont work because like I said before it need to use new operator. the error code [E2459 Delphi style classes must be constructed using operator new]. And I am using C++ Builder. NOT Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: And to assign property value to a TObject using C++ Builder is using -> not dot[.] so, the correct one is asd->text

Comment: @Yokowasis: `TButton`'s constructor requires a pointer to the form or parent.  You'll need to add that in the parens of `TButton(...)`.  I will update my third example to use a smart pointer instead.

Comment: already tried it. this code [TButton *asd; asd = new TButton(this);] works perfectly  outside my class. For example when I put it in the onclick function. But when I move it inside my function, it refuses to work.

Comment: @JohnZwinck tried, your first, and 3rd code. Still won't work. Perhaps a screenshot will help. http://i.snag.gy/asDNs.jpg & http://i.snag.gy/4yEYY.jpg

Comment: @Yokowasis: `std::unique_ptr` isn't working because you've not enabled C++11 mode in your project.  First try doing that.  As for the error in `(...)` that's because YOU have to fill in the `...` with the appropriate value (a pointer to a TForm, perhaps).

Comment: @JohnZwinck thanks. the 3rd code works perfectly. Thanks man. How do you enabled C++11 mode in Rad Studio ?

Comment: @Yokowasis: from my reading online, Rad Studio may not support C++11 fully yet, maybe never.  Oh well.  :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck well, at least my problem solved. Thank you very much Man.